# Why theme.css is minified and what's the proper way to edit it?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using prestashop 1.7.6.7. And when I wanted to edit theme.css I noticed that this file is minified even all performance settings are disabled.

Could someone explain why this file is minified and what's the best way to edit theme.css ?

Note: When I made a change it's automatically change in front.

Comment: There must be a custom.css file in the assets folder. Put your code/override in a custom file.

Comment: @Sachin Adding css in custom.css will waste my time. As i have each time to extract class, action (hover, ...), or device type to customize it. Besides locating the change  in theme.css is really easy.

Comment: Okay. Can you check performance in admin? Make sure CCC is disabled.

Comment: Optimisation Apache, Smart Cache for CSS and Smart Cache for JS are disabled

Comment: Then unmimify the css and make changes. Then upload it. Go to https://unminify.com/

Comment: Can prestashop 1.7 modify or minify it?

Comment: Maybe your store has a module installed which minifies the CSS of your theme.